# Calculating normal and curvature for a parameterized curve in space

Tags: differential-geometry

I've been working through the online material for a differential geometry course from a couple years ago [I won't mention it directly to avoid homework answers turning up in a web search]. I think I'm following things ok but I've gotten stuck hard on one of the early exercises; I've put several days of work into it and reviewed all the relevant material, so I wonder if I'm misunderstanding or approaching things wrong.

The question is: find the normal and curvature for the parameterized curve $\phi(t) = (t, t^2, t^3)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I can find *an* answer, more or less, but it involves such large and ugly formulas that I feel like it can't possibly be right. Here's what I've done:

The derivative of the curve is $\frac{d\phi}{dt} = (1, 2t, 3t^2)$, the second derivative is $\frac{d^2 \phi}{d^2 t} = (0, 2, 6t)$.

To get a vector *parallel* to the normal, we can project the second derivative orthogonally to the first derivative (the definition given of the normal is the normalized derivative of the unit tangent; projecting instead lets us leave the normalization step til last, giving slightly cleaner calculations, though I've confirmed that I get the same answer even when I do normalize first):

$$
(0,2,6t) - \frac{\langle (0,2,6t), (1,2t,3t^2) \rangle}{\lVert (1,2t,3t^2) \rVert^2} (1, 2t, 3t^2) \\
= \left(\frac{1}{9t^4 + 4t^2 + 1}\right) (-18t^3 - 4t, -18t^4 + 2, 12t^3 + 6t)
$$

There are now two directions we can go: on the one hand, we can correct for the fact that we used a non-normalized tangent by dividing this whole thing by the length of the first derivative, giving

$$
(9t^4 + 4t^2 + 1)^{-3/2} (-18t^3 - 4t, -18t^4 + 2, 12t^3 + 6t) = \kappa N
$$

($\kappa$ the curvature, $N$ the normal)

On the other hand, we can throw out the coefficient and just keep the vector, and normalizing it to unit length gives:

$$
N = \frac{(-18t^3 - 4t, -18t^4 + 2, 12t^3 + 6t)}{\lVert (-18t^3 - 4t, -18t^4 + 2, 12t^3 + 6t) \rVert} \\
= \frac{(-18t^3 - 4t, -18t^4 + 2, 12t^3 + 6t)}{\sqrt{324 t^8 + 468 t^6 + 216 t^4 + 52 t^2 + 4}}
$$

(and with a bit more similar manipulation we can combine these to produce a formula for $\kappa$ itself that I won't reproduce here.)

So my question is: can this possibly be right? Am I missing something? I got so stuck on this that I gave up on the class entirely for a while before coming back and working through it all again, and it still seems strange to me. If I came to this problem on my own I might think "oh, I guess this one just has an ugly closed form" but this is one-third of one problem on an assignment that has 20 more problems after this, and I've found the other material in the class to be clear and approachable (and the example normal calculations in lecture+notes are on the order of like... a circle), so I really don't know what to make of this one.

Comment: I haven’t checked your work but my guess is that the solution really is a big mess. That’s the case with most parametrized curves defined using explicit formulas. I think you can safely skip this problem.

Comment: You might want to download my differential geometry text (free access at the link in my profile) to see discussion and examples of working with the Frenet equations with non-arclength-parametrized curves.